# Sorting HashSet

Tags: java, sorting

I have written a program to insert data in a HashSet...here is the code

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>
{
    private int person_id;
    private String person_name;
    public Person(int person_id,String person_name)
    {
        this.person_id=person_id;
        this.person_name=person_name;
    }
    /* getter and setter method */
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        Person p=(Person)obj;
        if(!(p instanceof Person))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(this.person_id==p.person_id)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return person_id*6;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o)
    {
        if(this.person_id>o.person_id)
            return 1 ;
        else if(this.person_id<o.person_id)
            return -1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

I havent pasted other two classes.All i am doing in those classes is populating the data and other is main class.

Now i understand that through Java Doc Api i came to know that there is method called sort() in Collections class.Now the issue which i am is that sort mathod takes list.

here is signature from doc  sort(List list). I am facing problem to sort my hashset .Somebody told me to convert HashSet into TreeSet(Thats also mentioned in one of the thread is stackoverflow)...Is this the only way

Comment: Why not get rid of `HashSet` and just use `TreeSet` from the start?

Answer (score 9):

Pretty much the only way. **`HashSet` was never meant to be sorted.** It does not keep any ordering of your items, in exchange for performance of `contains`, `add` and `remove` operations.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). **It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time**. This class permits the null element.

So, just use `TreeSet` which keeps the sorting according to your class' natural ordering. I see your class implements `Comparable` which makes it readily be used in a `TreeSet`

Comment: I more question i want its regarding map...can i put in same thread?

Answer (score 0):

Use **`LinkedHashSet`** instead, as It insert elements in a sorted manner, so the set is always sorted.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html more information:

> **Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order**. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the set. (An element e is reinserted into a set s if s.add(e) is invoked when s.contains(e) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)